# Creating global secondary index from CLI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am hoping someone can help me with Dynamo CLI syntax.

I have been unable to create a global secondary index from the CLI.

My script before the index works as expected:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--table-name a.b.c \
--attribute-definitions \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,KeyType=HASH \
--provisioned-throughput\
  ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
--endpoint-url $DATABASE_ENDPOINT_URL
```

When I add the index, I get an error:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--table-name a.b.c \
--attribute-definitions \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,AttributeType=S \
  AttributeName=BatchID,AttributeType=S \
  AttributeName=TransactionStatus,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,KeyType=HASH \
--global-secondary-indexes IndexName=a.b.indexName,\
  KeySchema=["{AttributeName=BatchID,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=TransactionStatus,KeyType=RANGE}"],\
  Projection="{ProjectionType=KEYS_ONLY}",\
  ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5}"\
--provisioned-throughput\
  ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
--endpoint-url $DATABASE_ENDPOINT_URL
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error parsing parameter '--global-secondary-indexes': Expected: '<second>', received: '<none>' for input: IndexName=a.b.indexName,
```

This seems to be straight from the examples. I have also tried using a file based on some examples from other questions, but have had no luck there either.

Comment: I had the same mistake. I fixed  removing the spaces after "\"

Answer (score 5):

Putting everything on one line fixed it.

This works:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--table-name a.b.c \
--attribute-definitions \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,AttributeType=S \
  AttributeName=BatchID,AttributeType=S \
  AttributeName=TransactionStatus,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema \
  AttributeName=TransactionID,KeyType=HASH \
--global-secondary-indexes IndexName=a.b.indexName,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=BatchID,KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=TransactionStatus,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=KEYS_ONLY}",ProvisionedThroughput="{ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5}"\
--provisioned-throughput\
  ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
--endpoint-url $DATABASE_ENDPOINT_URL
```